# Implement node copy and paste feature in jsMind library

Tags: javascript, copy, nodes, paste

community,
I am using the JsMind library as the mind-mapping tool for my React app. Everything was good and what is only left is the copy-and-paste feature for the nodes. This is the repo URL: https://github.com/hizzgdev/jsmind I see this copy-paste-related issue but didn't see any implementation. https://github.com/hizzgdev/jsmind/issues/445

Did anyone try this feature out?